# How to find rectangle shape in this image using python?

Tags: python, image-processing, shapes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAQBs.jpg)can you help me to segment rectangular objects in this image, tried otsu but it is not working because background and forground have same values.

is there any other method to do the same.

Can somebody please tell me how to find a rectangle object in these images?
Images are results of canny edge detection. Actually I want to track these rectangles in a video, if you know how to do it please tell me.
OR at least I want to find whether a rectangle is present or not. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6ELg.jpg)

Comment: Is approximately a rectangle regarded as a rectangle or do you need 90 degrees corners and same lengths for it to actually be a rectangle?

Comment: i want approximate rectangle, because in video frames shape may change slightly, you can see difference in two images.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at rows and columns of pixels. For example, the top border row of your rectangle contains many more black pixels than the row above. So I would suggest you to use vertical (through rows) and horizontal (through columns) passes to find the borders. Here's my script to do it:

```
from PIL import Image

FACTOR = 1.5 # a threashold

img = Image.open("path/to/your/image")
pix = img.load()
size = img.size

# vertical pass
sum_color_arr = []
for row_num in xrange(size[1]):
    sum_color = 0 # calculating of brightness for each row separately
    for i in xrange(size[0]):
        sum_color += pix[i, row_num]
    sum_color_arr.append(sum_color)

for row_num in xrange(size[1] - 1):
    if sum_color_arr[row_num] > FACTOR * sum_color_arr[row_num + 1]:
        print "Top border: y =", (row_num + 1)
    if sum_color_arr[row_num + 1] > FACTOR * sum_color_arr[row_num]:
        print "Bottom border: y =", row_num

# horizontal pass
sum_color_arr = []
for col_num in xrange(size[0]):
    sum_color = 0 # calculating of brightness for each column separately
    for i in xrange(size[1]):
        sum_color += pix[col_num, i]
    sum_color_arr.append(sum_color)

for col_num in xrange(size[0] - 1):
    if sum_color_arr[col_num] > FACTOR * sum_color_arr[col_num + 1]:
        print "Left border: x =", (col_num + 1)
    if sum_color_arr[col_num + 1] > FACTOR * sum_color_arr[col_num]:
        print "Right border: x =", col_num
```

Comment: i am trying to execute your code...getting this error  in line  sum_color += sum(pix[i, row_num])

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: using python 2.7 only, still i am getting same error. Have attached original image [enter image description here][1]
this is my code for canny edge detection..can you pls check your code.
    frame=cv2.imread('imagepath')
    framegray1=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    framegray=cv2.blur(framegray1,(3,3))
    edge1=feature.canny(framegray,sigma=3)
    edge11=ndimage.binary_closing(edge1)
    edge2=np.uint8(edge11)
    edge2[edge2==1]=255 # this is canny edge image    
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O26np.jpgv

Comment: Maybe this error occures because of black and white colors only in your pic... Usually pix[,] returns a tuple of RGB, but it seems for you it returns an integer. So you don't need to sum it. I removed `sum` from the script. Please, try again.

Comment: now its working but there is a chance of additional pixels because of change in light intensity, then how this code detects only rectangular shape..

Comment: I suppose changing of `FACTOR` might be enough for most cases you are going to use this solution. If not, you need another approach...

Comment: ok..have edited my question with other image, can you please suggest me how to segment white rectangle shapes from background...

Comment: Omg... I can't see any rectangle even with my eyes. Haha! These sharp clouds are supposed to be rectangles?

Comment: yes yes...they are actually rectangles but after stacking it got compressed and look like white clouds

Comment: This detail makes your task much more complicated. Please, have a look at OpvenCV examples: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_table_of_contents_feature2d/py_table_of_contents_feature2d.html#py-table-of-content-feature2d . I hope it is capable to help you.